# CMS Open source c#

Tags: open-source, c#, cms, asp.net

can you recommend me a open source CMS made with C#?
Before, I used PHP and wordpress but on my new work I use C# and asp.net core to make web, I'm looking for a CSM open source like wordpress but made with c# 
Thanks you to help me.

Comment: Generally, I would start here: http://www.cmsmatrix.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below open-source CMS systems

- N2 CMS.
- Atomic CMS
- Orchard Project
- DotNetNuke
- Umbraco.

---

The source: https://www.dailyrazor.com/blog/aspnet-hosting/best-aspnet-cms-for-aspnet-developers